# Flushing rewrite rules

Tags: url-rewriting, urls

I'm using this function to add a custom end point to the WordPress urls

```
add_rewrite_endpoint('print', EP_ALL);
```

When the plug-in gets deactivated, I run this function

```
flush_rewrite_rules();
```

This flush the rewrite rules, and disable the 'print' end point. Fine. But I'm thinking of other plug-ins. What if other plug-ins have registered some rewrite rules. Will they be flushed too?

If so, how can I preserve them as this will run their rewrite rules.
And the same being for my plug-in. Do you have to re-register the rules everytime WordPress is called?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What `flush_rewrite_rules();` does is call `$wp_rewrite->flush_rules();` (Also called when updating permalinks).
All plugins rewrite rules are regenerated then, so you dont need to worry about other plugins rules being "missing".

Also is not a good idea to call this function (`flush_rewrite_rule`) on hooks that run each time wordpress is loaded, and is enough to call `add_rewrite_endpoint` or `add_rewrite_rule` on activation or deactivation hooks.

Comment: It was my understanding that you should added the rewrite rule on each load, but only flush on activation/deactivation.